# How do I "stick" the "Terminal" window to Launcher a.k.a. Unity Panel?

Tags: unity, launcher, keyboard, panel, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add programs to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224004/how-to-add-programs-to-the-launcher)

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. By now I have discovered that I need to launch the Terminal window whenever I run programs.

Hence I would like to stick the Terminal window to the Launcher a.k.a. Unity Panel.

Can it be done?

If it can't be done, what keyboard shortcuts are there to quickly bring up the Terminal window?

As of now, I have to click on the Dash Home icon, click on the second left icon on the little menu bar at the bottom of the Dash Home window, click on Installed (see more results) in order to bring up a Terminal window.