# MuseScore Won't Lock to the Dock

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, snap, ubuntu-dock, musescore

I installed MuseScore on Ubuntu 18.04 using snap from the terminal.

After I installed it I wanted to add it to the dock. Instead of the usual 'Add to Favorites' I get 'Quit' and 'All Windows >'.

What do I need to do to add MuseScore to the Dock?

Comment: Have you installed Musescore properly as shown here: [Stable releases of MuseScore](https://launchpad.net/~mscore-ubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/mscore-stable). I found these versions of dock for ubuntu: [version 1](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-customize-dock-panel-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) and [version 2](https://www.fossmint.com/macos-like-docks-for-ubuntu/). Check you have installed it properly by reinstalling it.

Comment: Okay, I just tested on my Bionic installation, it's completely reproducible. MuseScore application installed as a snap doesn't show any "add to favourites" option indeed as the question describes. But searching for the application in Activities overview, and then clicking and dragging it across to the dock (check ["method 2" here](https://askubuntu.com/a/224010/480481)) does pin it to the dock.